# A grammatically valid sentence in English containing seven "that"'s in a row?

Tags: word-problem, english, language

About 20 years ago on a forum now long gone, someone posted the above question. After people had had a chance to try it, he also posted the answer. I no longer remember the answer but really wish I did.

The answer was not along the lines of "I want that, that, that, that, that, that, and that."

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: LOL! that was thaty question

Comment: are you going to tick a correct question?

Comment: @d'alar'cop You mean a correct answer ;-)

Comment: @rand surely I did... wine?

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_linguistic_example_sentences

Comment: sorry, I wandered off for a few years. I've ticked a correct answer. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found it:

> "It is true for all that that that that that that that refers to is not the same that that that that refers to."

Meaning:

> It is true for all that, that that "that" which that "that" refers to is not the same "that" which that "that" refers to.
>
> Or perhaps more clearly: It is true, despite everything you say, that this word to which this word refers is not the same word to which this word refers.

For a clearer parsing: [HERE](https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Power_Of_Seven/Seven_Thats_2948.htm)

This one has 5:

> "He said that that that that that boy used was incorrect."

Meaning:

> He said that a particular boy's particular usage of the word "that" was incorrect

Comment: Here's a comedic related one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_that_is_is_that_that_is_not_is_not_is_that_it_it_is

Comment: you could string together an infinite "that that, that" as each one is narrowing down the object

Comment: @Keltari you're right.

Comment: Wow, this is amazingly surprising! I never considered that that that sentence was possible.

Comment: Related to [James while John had had had had had had had had had had had a better effect on the teacher](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher)